# How to stream webrtc video from the phone in background

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webrtc, capacitor

I have an application that allows users to stream video and audio from their phones using webrtc to the server. The streaming should not be interrupted if the device locks down or the app goes to background. Everything works perfectly in the first case. In the second case, however, when I press the home button, audio still works perfectly but the video freezes. Any help would be much appreciated here.

P.S. I'm using ionic with capacitor.

Comment: I haven't found any so I had to use a workaround: I simply blacked out the screen to make it look like the phone is in the background.